# Javascript Phone Validation

Tags: javascript

I want if phone number starts with + it should accept 12 digits if it does not contain + it should accept 10 digit what changes I have to do?
My code is attached below.

```
function phvalid()
{
    var a = document.getElementById('phone').value;
    var gb = /^([0|\+[0-9]{1,5})?([7-9][0-9]{9})$/;
    if (a=="") {
        document.getElementById('ph').innerHTML="Enter Number";
    }
    if (a.match(gb))
    {  
        document.getElementById("ph").innerHTML="";  
        // return true;  
    }
    if(a.length!=10)
    {  
        document.getElementById("ph").innerHTML="Enter 10 digits";  
        return false;  
    }
    if(a.indexOf("+")==0)
    {  
        document.getElementById("ph").innerHTML="Enter 12 digits";  
        return false;  
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('ph').innerHTML=""; 
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you..!! I have used the simple startwith method.

```js
function phoneValidator() {
  var number = document.getElementById('phoneNumber').value
  if(number.startsWith("+")) {
    document.getElementById("phoneNumber").maxLength = 12;
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("phoneNumber").maxLength = 10;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber" onkeyup="phoneValidator()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your check for 10 digits overrides your check for 12. What I would do is:

```
function phvalid()
{
    let phone = document.getElementById('phone');
    let regex = /^([0|\+[0-9]{1,5})?([7-9][0-9]{9})$/;
    if (phone.value=="") {
        phone.innerHTML="Enter Number";
    }
    if (phone.value.match(regex))
    {  
        phone.value.innerHTML="";  
        // return true;  
    }
    if ( phone.value.charAt(0) != '+' && phone.value.length != 12 ){
        if ( phone.value.length != 10 ){
            phone.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid phone number, it should be 10 digits unless it is international in which case it should be 12 prefixed by a +";
            return;
        } else {
            // Do whatever you need to do for a 10 digit phone number
        }
    } else {
        // Do whatever you need to do for a 12 digit number
    }
}
```

It is always easier to read your code later if you explain what you are doing, to yourself. The nested if, yes you could do it all on one line or use an iif there but when you come back to read it later, this will probably be easier to understand. I also set the result of the document.getElementById to a variable for both less typing and to make it clear what you are modifying. Your code you are modifying a different element. If that's what you are trying to do, it is still easier than calling getElementById every time you wish to modify it, calling and storing it means you only have to change it in one place if your code changes later instead of having a weird bug because you forgot to change it somewhere.

If I'm reading your regex right, the 10 digit phone number must start with a 0? It might be better to use:

```
let regex=/(^\+?\d{10,12}$)/;
```